# How do I combine 2 recursive functions into a single one?

Tags: recurrence-relations, systems-of-equations

I'm trying to find the growth speed of a certain sequence, but its recursive formula requires additional state - resulting in a system of recursive equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
F_1(n)=F_1(n-1)+F_2(n-3)\\ 
F_2(n)=F_1(n-1)+F_2(n-1)\\
\end{cases}
$$

Is there a way to collapse these two into a single equation for $F_1$? Or to find how fast it gets bigger in some other way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll write the values of $F_1$ in the first row and $F_2$ in the second row. If you start computing, you'll notice that you need an initial state of the form

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b & c \\
d & \cdot & \cdot
\end{bmatrix}
$$

You can then extend the table to

$$
\begin{bmatrix}a & b & c & c+d \\
d & {a+d} & \cdot & \cdot \end{bmatrix}
$$

Forgetting the first row, we see that increasing $n$ by 1 has amounted to applying the mapping

$$
\begin{bmatrix}a & b & c \\ d & \cdot & \cdot\end{bmatrix} \mapsto
\begin{bmatrix}b & c & c+d \\ a+d & \cdot & \cdot\end{bmatrix}
$$

This is is the linear mapping

$$
\begin{pmatrix} a \\ b \\ c \\ d \end{pmatrix}
\mapsto
\begin{pmatrix} b \\ c \\ c+d \\ a+d \end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} a \\ b \\ c \\ d \end{pmatrix}
$$

I'll write this as

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
F_1(n)\\ F_1(n+1) \\ F_1(n+2) \\ F_2(n)
\end{pmatrix}
=
M^n
\begin{pmatrix}
F_1(0)\\ F_1(1) \\ F_1(2) \\ F_2(0)
\end{pmatrix},
$$

where $M$ is the matrix above. By diagonalizing $M$, you can get an explicit formula. I notice that the complex eigenvalue with the largest modulus is the golden ratio $\frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}$. So these should grow about like the Fibonacci sequence.

Edit: you can also explicitly isolate a recurrence for $F_1$, if need be:

\begin{align*}
    F_1(n)
    &= F_1(n-1) + F_2(n-3)
    \\&= F_1(n-1) + F_1(n-4) + F_2(n-4)
    \\&= F_1(n-1) + F_1(n-4) + \big(F_1(n-1) - F_1(n-2)\big)
    \\&= 2F_1(n-1) - F_1(n-2) + F_1(n-4).
\end{align*}

Comment: Wouldn't "explicit formula" still contain $F_2$?

Comment: It would contain the base case $F_2(0)$.

Comment: I'm looking for formula without $F_2$, since it's not part of the sequence I'm interested in (it's an additional state that came up in deriving this system of equations). Is there any way to apply characteristic polynomial from @DroneBetter answer?

Comment: If you want, you could write that $F_2(0)$ as $F_1(3) - F_1(2)$.

Comment: @NooneAtAll3 does that last edit help?

Comment: oooh, deriving $F_1$ is much easier than I thought. Now I feel stupid, ha

Comment: note that the final recursion for $F_1$  comes directly from the characteristic polynomial for matrix $M$

Answer (score 4):

Any such recurrence you can write as a single matrix operation. You need a few extra states to hold recent values: $$
\begin{cases}
F_1(n)=F_1(n-1)+F_2(n-3)\\ 
F_2(n)=F_1(n-1)+F_2(n-1)\\
\end{cases}
$$
Becomes: $$
\left[
\begin{matrix}
F_1(n)\\
F_2(n)\\
F_2(n-1)\\
F_2(n-2)
\end{matrix}
\right]=
\left[
\begin{matrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0
\end{matrix}
\right]
\left[
\begin{matrix}
F_1(n-1)\\
F_2(n-1)\\
F_2(n-2)\\
F_2(n-3)
\end{matrix}
\right]
$$
You can find the eigenvalues of that matrix to see how fast the system grows.

Answer (score 1):

Store them as a vector, then$$
F(n)=\begin{pmatrix}F(n-1)_1+F(n-3)_2\\F(n-1)_1+F(n-1)_2\end{pmatrix}\\
=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\1&1\end{pmatrix}*F(n-1)+\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}*F(n-3)
$$Just as with the field of complex numbers, you can express $F(n)$ in terms of a linear combination of $n$th powers of the matrices that are roots of the characteristic polynomial, $\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}-\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\1&1\end{pmatrix}*x-\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}*x^3$, times vector coefficients. Due to the analytic form for exponentiating $2\times2$ matrices to noninteger powers, each component ($F_1$ and $F_2$) has an analytic form for its function over $n$.